# How to write a csv file with timestamp in filename, to a new folder with timestamp name under a directory different from CWD?

Tags: python, csv, file-handling

I am writing a script that will go through different folders in a shared drive and summarizes some data. This part works fine. However I want to write the results to a csv file. Every time I run the script, I want a folder to be created under a project folder in My Documents, with the folder name as current time stamp, and the csv file name should be like "Analysis- timestamp". My code currently creates the new folder with time stamp as name, but throws an error for the csv file creation part.

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime

dt=datetime.now()
timestamp=dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
resultfolder=Path("C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Python Scripts/Analysis_results")
csvpath= os.path.join(resultfolder, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
os.makedirs(csvpath)
path = Path(csvpath)
fpath= (path / timestamp ).with_suffix('.csv')
finals_public = Path("C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/vault1/Reports/Finals_Public")
os.chdir(finals_public)
with fpath.open(mode='w+') as f:
    w=csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(["DSFlist"])
    for bfr in glob.glob('DSF-*'):
        w.writerow([bfr])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File xxxxxx.py:26 in 
> with fpath.open(mode='w+') as f:
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py:1252 in open
> return io.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline,
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py:1120 in _opener
> return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Python
> Scripts\Analysis_results\2022-07-21_10-06-21\21-Jul-2022
> (10:06:21.csv'

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get // in the filepath in the error?

Comment: Does the Folder exist? If not create the folder first. Path does not check automatically if the Folder exists

Comment: @Tomerikoo I first wanted to ask if it exists it have to be something else. But if not this would be the Solution

Comment: @Tomerikoo sry I am dumb ^^'